# What font is in the search box?

Tags: css, search, fonts

Please quickly check out this site:

http://go.frenchlabs.net/

I want to get the font that is used in the search box. What do you think it is? I like how it is a very thin font, how is this achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's Helvetica Neue Light. You can find out this information using Firebug (Firefox) or Web Inspector (Chrome and Safari).

Right-click the element on the page you are interested in and then click 'Inspect Element':

[image]

Then you will be able to see all of the attributes of that element:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Where do I right click i am using safari but nothing comes up apart from the obvious view source code ect.

Comment: What version of Safari are you using? Move your mouse over the input field, and then right click. At the bottom of the context menu, you should be able to see Inspect Element.

Comment: I am using Safari 4.1.3 on 10.4.11, i think its too old!

Comment: Try the following: Safari > Preferences > Advanced, and click on the "Show Develop menu in menu bar." Then try the right-click.

Answer (score 2):

That answer is based on Chrome console :

font: 300 19px 'HelveticaNeue-Light', "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif